# Does Gitlab EE Have Audit Logs for "git clone", and "git pull" commands?

Tags: gitlab, audit, gitlab-ee

The [audit events page of gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html) says that I can find "Project repository was downloaded" action in **Project** > **Settings** > **Audit Events**.

So I tried running `git clone http://gitlab.example.com/testauditlog.git` to download one of my projects. But then I can't find anything related to the download in the audit events. Why does this happen?

The only logs belonging to `git clone` I found is in `/var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log`

```
172.17.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2020:03:28:56 +0000] "GET /testauditlog.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 254 "" "git/2.21.0 (Apple Git-122.2)"
172.17.0.1 - - [03/Jan/2020:03:28:56 +0000] "POST /testauditlog.git/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 949 "" "git/2.21.0 (Apple Git-122.2)"
```

But this log doesn't say which account cloned the repository. So it is not that useful for the compliance team in my company.

I used [gitlab/gitlab-ee at dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ee/) with a 30-day evaluation license to try the audit events feature of gitlab.

Comment: any news of this features , i have the same issue